# Show/hide jquery datatable columns conditionally in an aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, show-hide

I have a radio button list in an apsx page and want to show/hide columns in a jQuery data table depending on radio button selection.

I managed to do it but it is painfully slow compared to just populating data in data table based on radio button selection and not touching the columns visibility.

This is what I have and what I have tried:

(assuming radio button list contains "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3" and "Option 4" as choices, plus "All").

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblOptions" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
    DataSourceID="odsOptionss"
    DataTextField="Option" 
    DataValueField="OptionID"
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="-1" Selected="True" />
</asp:RadioButtonList> 

<div runat="server" id="divAll" clientidmode="Static">
    <table id="svDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
                <th>Col4</th>
                <th>Col5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTableData">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td runat="server" id="tdCol1"><%# Eval("Col1Data") %></td>
                        <td runat="server" id="tdCol2"><%# Eval("Col2Data") %></td>
                        <td runat="server" id="tdCol3"><%# Eval("Col3Data") %></td>
                        <td runat="server" id="tdCol4"><%# Eval("Col4Data") %></td>
                        <td runat="server" id="tdCol5"><%# Eval("Col5Data") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script typeof="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        bindDataTable(); // bind data table on first page load
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindDataTable); // bind data table on every UpdatePanel refresh
    });

    function bindDataTable() {
        var selectedOption = $("#rblOptions input[type=radio]:checked");
        var optionId = selectedOption.val();
        var option = selectedOption.next().html();

        if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#svDataTable')) {
            table = $('#svDataTable').DataTable();
        }
        else {
            table = $('#svDataTable').DataTable({
                "bStateSave": true,
                "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
                    localStorage.setItem('svDataTable', JSON.stringify(oData));
                },
                "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
                    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('svDataTable'));
                }
            });
        }
        switch (option) {
            case 'All':
                break;

            case 'Option 1':
                table.column(3).visible(false);
                table.column(4).visible(false);
                table.column(5).visible(false);
                break;

            case 'Option 2':
                table.column(2).visible(false);
                table.column(3).visible(false);
                break;

            case 'Option 3':
                break;

            case 'Option 4':
                table.column(1).visible(false);
                table.column(2).visible(false);
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Update**

I adapted Alex's suggestion like below, although I am not sure if I understood Alex correctly and if am doing it correctly. I guess not becuasee "debugger" I put in the script never gets hit.:

```
$(function () {
    bindDataTable(); // bind data table on first page load
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindDataTable); // bind data table on every UpdatePanel refresh
});

function bindDataTable() {
    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#svDataTable')) {
        table = $('#svDataTable').DataTable();
    }
    else {
        table = $('#svDataTable').DataTable({
            "bStateSave": true,
            "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
                localStorage.setItem('svDataTable', JSON.stringify(oData));
            },
            "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('svDataTable'));
            }
        });
    }
}

$('#rblSysType').on('click', '[type=radio]', function () {
    var tbl = $('#svDataTable');
    $('td, th', tbl).show();
debugger
    var selectedSysType = $("#rblSysType input[type=radio]:checked");
    var sysTypeId = selectedSysType.val();
    var sysType = selectedSysType.next().html();

    switch (sysType) {
        case 'Option 2':
        case 'Opion 4':
        case 'All':
             break;

        case 'Option 1':
            $('tr>*:nth-child(8)', tbl).hide();
            $('tr>*:nth-child(9)', tbl).hide();
            $('tr>*:nth-child(10)', tbl).hide();
            $('tr>*:nth-child(11)', tbl).hide();
            $('tr>*:nth-child(12)', tbl).hide();
            $('tr>*:nth-child(13)', tbl).hide();
            break;

        case 'Option 3':
            $('tr>*:nth-child(11)', tbl).hide();
            $('tr>*:nth-child(12)', tbl).hide();
            $('tr>*:nth-child(13)', tbl).hide();
            break;

        case 'Option 5':
            $('tr>*:nth-child(11)', tbl).hide();
            $('tr>*:nth-child(12)', tbl).hide();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `RadioButtonList` has **`ID="rblOptions`** and in JS you use **`#rblSysType`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<asp:RadioButtonList` is rendered as a list of `input type="radio"` and the `Repeater` in your example is a `table`. So what you want can be easily done on the client side. Something like this.

**Update based on OP update**

ASP.NET can add prefixes to a control ID so it is smart to use CSS classes instead. Just make sure they are unique on the page.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblOptions" CssClass="make-list"...
```

**Final update**

First decide what you exactly want.

If content **and layout** of the repeater depend on the `RadioButtonList` selection then the best choice is to use server-side code (with RadioButtonList `AutoPostBack="true"`) and decide what to show/hide in `repeater_ItemDataBound` handler.
If you still want to add some client-side code then call that code from

```
ScriptManagerRegisterStartupScript(...
```

```js
$('.make-list').on('click', '[type=radio]', function() {
  //var make = this.parentNode.innerText; //if you want to use text instead of value (not recommended)
  var tbl = $('#svDataTable');
  $('td, th', tbl).show();
  if (this.value == -1)
    return; //show all
  switch (this.value) {//**this** is radio button clicked
    case "1":
      $('tr>*:nth-child(1),tr>*:nth-child(3)', tbl).hide();
      break;
    case "2":
      $('tr>*:nth-child(2),tr>*:nth-child(3),tr>*:nth-child(5)', tbl).hide();
      break;
    default:
      $('tr>*:nth-child(' + this.value + ')', tbl).hide();
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opts" class="make-list">Hide a column
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt" value="-1" />show all</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt" value="1" />one</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt" value="2" />two</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt" value="3" />three</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt" value="4" />four</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="opt" value="5" />five</label>
</div>
<table id="svDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <th>Col4</th>
      <th>Col5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>dat 1.1</td>
      <td>dat 1.2</td>
      <td>dat 1.3</td>
      <td>dat 1.4</td>
      <td>dat 1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dat 2.1</td>
      <td>dat 2.2</td>
      <td>dat 2.3</td>
      <td>dat 2.4</td>
      <td>dat 2.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Plus bootstrap.css

Comment: thank you Alex. Option values and table columns don't match exactly; if I select "option 2" I don't want to hide column 2 . I used those as an example. The option are actually machine types and some columns don't apply to selected machine type (e.g. some columns are always empty for selected machine type) so I need to remove those columns. It could be "remove columns 1, 3 and 4 when option 1 is selected" and "remove columns 2 and 5 when option 2 is selected". Look at the "switch" statement in my question's javascript part.

Comment: I updated my question based on Alex's response. Still can't get it to work.

Comment: remove `AutoPostBack="true"` from `RadioButtonList`. The solution works on client side.

Comment: I followed the instructions; added css class, removed autopostback but when I click on an option, the function does not get hit (I added "debugger" inside the function to see if it gets hit). Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I meant I added "debugger" inside the function in my code not the snippet. I did manage to make it work by adding "onclick='Some_function();" to radio button list and in that function I added the code you had provided (with case statement and hiding columns). However, because I had remove autopostback, now the data in the table doesn't get updated when I select different options and if I add the autopostback, column hiding doesn't work. I am down to last few strands of my hair!

Comment: I'm afraid you run into *x/y problem* https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your last update worked. I added ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upnlPC, GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:rblSysTypeClicked(); ", true); to repeater's pre-render method; upnlPC is the update panel repeater is in. It is working now, columns hide/show and data in table is updated. Thanks for the help. I will try to follow x/y problem too, thanks for that.